Solving system of power sum symmetric polynomials
I'm interested in solving the following system of $n$ equations in the unknowns $x_i, i=1, ..., n$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x^k_i = \alpha_k$$
where $k=1, ..., n$. The LHS is the power sum symmetric polynomial of degree k. The system is symmetric under a permutation of the unknowns, so I would expect $n!$ equivalent solutions.
As a particular and easier case, I'm interested in the same system when $\alpha_k=0$ when $k$ is odd. Under this hypothesis, we can halve the number of variables by setting $x_i = -x_{n+1-i}$ for $i=1, ... floor[n/2]$, and eventually $x_{\frac{n+1}{2}}=0$ if $n$ is odd. This condition automatically satisfies all equation for odd $k$, and we are left with the even $k$ equation which will look like
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{floor[n/2]} x^k_i = 2 \alpha_k := \beta_k$$
One can attempt to rewrite the equations by exploiting the following relation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{floor[n/2]} x^k_i = (\sum_{i=1} x^{k/2} _i) ^2  - \sum_{i,j=1}^{floor[n/2]} x^{k/2}_i x^{k/2}_j $$
but I'm not sure this helps in giving a solution. In the case a closed solution is not possible, I'm looking for efficient ways of numerically solving this system. Also, I would like to know if the solutions (especially in the particular case) are always real.

Are you familiar with Newtons identities which allow you to convert these into the symmetric polynomials and then let $x_i$ be the roots of a polynomial with coefficients in $a_i$?

@CalvinLin It seems you are referring to this. Looks straightforward, thanks. If you post I'll accept the answer

Go ahead and answer your own question :)  I can take a quick look after you posted, to see if there are any issues.

Thanks to Calvin in the comments. Following wikipedia, we can write the monic polynomial with roots $x_1, ..., x_n$ as
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (x-x_i) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k e_k x^{n-k}$$
where the $e_k$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $k$. Then, $e_k$ can be recursively obtained  as
$$e_k= \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i-1} e_{k-i} p_i $$
where $p_i$ is the power sum symmetric polynomials of degree $i$, and $e_0=1$.
So in our case we can write a polynomial of degree $n$ whose coefficients depend exclusively on $p_i$ (and so $\alpha_i$, as defined in the question) and solve for its roots numerically.
